# What is an encrypted LVM?

Tags: debian, partition, lvm, encryption

If I install Debian, I can choose to set up the disk using an encrypted LVM. But what exactly does this set up? Is just the partition table encrypted, or are all files on all partitions encrypted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use this option, the installer creates a few partitions: a `/boot` partition, which is used to store the kernel and bootloader; depending on your system, a special firmware (e.g., EFI) partition; and an encrypted partition which contains a single LVM physical volume.

Inside that encrypted LVM physical volume, there is a root partition and usually a swap partition, plus any additional partitions you want.  All of these partitions are encrypted, but the `/boot` and `/boot/efi` partitions are not.

It is never possible to encrypt the EFI partition, since the firmware doesn't know how to boot it in such a state.  It is *possible*, but uncommon, to encrypt the `/boot` partition; grub requires special configuration to do so, which Debian doesn't implement by default.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how much overhead that causes?

Comment: Assuming you're on a system with native AES instructions and you're using AES for your disk encryption, you can encrypt data much faster than you can write to disk, even with NVMe.  As for LVM, it's likely negligible in this configuration.  I haven't measured, though, so you'd have to measure to see if it makes a difference in your case.  I still recommend an encrypted disk regardless, though.

Comment: Why would you recommend this?

Comment: Because computers can be lost, stolen, or seized and when the computer is off, disk encryption protects the data on it from being accessed.  For example, my laptop could be stolen or seized by customs, and an encrypted disk prevents my data from disclosure.

Comment: @hefe here's a 2019 estimate of encryption overhead https://www.phoronix.com/review/2019-linux-encrypt